# Replacing multi-dimensional array values with values in another multi-dimensional arrray

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

So long story short, I have two arrays:

`$players` - This array matches player names to their ids by round

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    '[GPS]Alt_Stab' => '1',
    '[SUC]Caution' => '43',
    '[SUC]Ralphis' => '42',
    '[gps]dranzer' => '23',
    '[gps]xen' => '123',
    '[suc]tony' => '34',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    '[SXP]Dragon' => '54',
    '[SXP]HumanBones' => '55',
    '[SXP]Torvald' => '62',
    '[TDT]DS' => '90',
    '[TDT]Dev' => '71',
    '[TDT]Heks' => '81',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    '[SXP]Dragon' => '39',
    '[SXP]HumanBones' => '55',
    '[TDT]DS' => '56',
    '[TDT]Dev' => '57',
    '[TDT]Heks' => '84',
    '[sxp]legion' => '65',
  ),
)
```

and

`$events` - This holds event data by round

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    1 => '5,,[SUC]Ralphis,18097663,0,0,0,1276,31,-16,20,0,13',
    2 => '15,[SUC]Ralphis,[GPS]Alt_Stab,18097667,1281,-54,-16,1317,-320,0,853016576,8,0',
    3 => '0,[SUC]Ralphis,[GPS]Alt_Stab,18097667,1281,-54,-16,1317,-320,0,45,0,11',
    4 => '15,[SUC]Caution,[gps]dranzer,18097674,913,381,-6,910,149,-8,802684928,8,0',
    5 => '0,[SUC]Caution,[gps]dranzer,18097674,913,381,-6,910,149,-8,100,0,11',
    etc.....),
  1 => 
  array (
    1 => '14,[TDT]Dev,,33266052,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0',
    2 => '14,[TDT]DS,,33266150,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0',
    3 => '14,[SXP]Dragon,,33266194,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0',
    4 => '14,[SXP]Torvald,,33266212,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,1,0',
    5 => '14,[SXP]Torvald,,33266216,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,1,0',
    etc.....),
  2 => 
  array (
    1 => '14,[SXP]Dragon,,33287616,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0',
    2 => '14,[TDT]DS,,33287659,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0',
    3 => '15,[TDT]Heks,[SXP]HumanBones,33287691,2150,63,0,2316,295,0,207093760,8,0',
    4 => '15,[SXP]HumanBones,[TDT]Heks,33287691,2313,257,0,2090,64,0,661389312,8,0',
    5 => '0,[SXP]HumanBones,[TDT]Heks,33287691,2313,257,0,2090,64,0,100,0,11',
```

I then have a loop set up that will iterate through each item in `$players`, and give me the player's name and their id

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $round_count; $i++) {
    foreach($players[$i] as $player_name=>$player_id) {
        /* do things here */
    }
}
```

I need to somehow search the event string within `$events[$round][$line]` for the `$player_name` and replace it with the `$player_id` and push the result to a new array `$r_events`.  I'd like to keep the same structure as `$events`.

Just as a note, `$players` and `$events` will always have the same amount of outermost keys.

`$round_count` will always equal the amount of outermost keys in both arrays.

`$round_count` holds the actual amount of rounds played, so `$event[$i-1]` within the above for loop should contain all the event data from round 1.

**TLDR:** I need to search `$events[$round][$value]` for `$players[$round][$key]` and replace it with `$players[$round][$value]`

**Expected Outcome:**

`$r_events`

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2085 [▼
    1 => "5,,PLAYERID,18097663,0,0,0,1276,31,-16,20,0,13"
    2 => "15,PLAYERID,PLAYERID,18097667,1281,-54,-16,1317,-320,0,853016576,8,0"
    3 => "0,PLAYERID,PLAYERID,18097667,1281,-54,-16,1317,-320,0,45,0,11"
    4 => "15,PLAYERID,PLAYERID,18097674,913,381,-6,910,149,-8,802684928,8,0"
    5 => "0,PLAYERID,PLAYERID,18097674,913,381,-6,910,149,-8,100,0,11"
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome you want?

Comment: I need to replace the player names in the event strings with their ids

Comment: put the expected outcome in your question. that will help everyone to find the solution

Comment: Why work with strings having comma-separated values? You should store things in proper variables, arrays, ...

Comment: this is how the log file is given to me, I don't have much control over how it looks unfortunately